# Feynman learning technique

Tags: feynman

There is a learning technique by Richard Feynman, which is known as the "Feynman learning technique", and consists of four steps:

1. Select a concept to learn.
2. Teach it to a child (or maybe an adult who has zero knowledge in that field).
3. Identify gaps in your explanation. Go back to the source material to better understand it.
4. Organize and simplify.

You can find its description, for example, [here](https://fs.blog/feynman-learning-technique/) or [here](https://www.colorado.edu/artssciences-advising/resource-library/life-skills/the-feynman-technique-in-academic-coaching).

But where can I find its original description, that is, the description provided by Richard Feynman himself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Some Feynman's quotes about learning an teaching

I do not think Feynman's learning technique is found in his video lectures or in *Surely you're joking Mr. Feynman* (maybe loosely based on his remarks when he was teaching in Brazil?). In those sources he rather explain what are his steps to follow the scientific method. Watch Cornell lecture *[The Character of Physical Law](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2NnquxdWFk&t=1006s&ab_channel=TalkReelTV)*.

Some academic sources cite *[Feynman's Lost Lecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%27s_Lost_Lecture)* for his technique, but I could not find it there. In the preface by by David L. and Judith R. Goodstein, they write:

> Feynman was a truly great teacher. He prided himself on being able to devise ways to explain even rhe most profound ideas to beginning students. Once, I said to him, "Dick, explain to me, so that I can understand it, why spin one-half particles obey Fermi-Dirac statistics." Sizing up his audience perfectly, Feynman said, "I'll prepare a freshman lecture on it." But he came back a few days later to say, "I couldn't do it. I couldn't reduce it to the freshman level. That means we don't really understand it."

Which shows his methodology, but it is still not very precise. There is no single recognized or clear source in academic sources so the method might have been invented by somebody else.

It is also interesting his account in Feynman's [1973 interview with Charles Wiener](https://www.aip.org/history-programs/niels-bohr-library/oral-histories/5020-5):

> You see I didn't know how much was known and how much was not known so it was more a matter of learning. For me to learn, I read a little bit and I work out the rest. I don’t really read a lot of what the other guy does. I read what his assumptions are and if they seem reasonable then I work out the conclusions.

Another interesting teach comes from his 1966 *[What is Science?](http://www.feynman.com/science/what-is-science/)* lecture

> I finally figured out a way to test whether you have taught an idea or you have only taught a definition.
>
> Test it this way: you say, “Without using the new word which you have just learned, try to rephrase what you have just learned in your own language.” Without using the word “energy,” tell me what you know now about the dog’s motion.” You cannot. So you learned nothing about science.

### Genius biography and its self-help book origin

The closest I have found so far is from the biography *Genius: The Life and Science of Richard Feynman* by James Gleick:

> In preparing for his oral qualifying examination, a rite of passage for every graduate student, he chose not to study the outlines of known physics. Instead he went up to MIT, where he could be alone, and opened a fresh notebook. On the title page he wrote: *Notebook Of Things I Don’t Know About*. For the first but
> not the last time he reorganized his knowledge. He worked for weeks at disassembling each branch of physics, oiling the parts, and putting them back together, looking all the while for the raw edges and inconsistencies.
> He tried to find the essential kernels of each subject. When he was done he had a notebook of which he was especially proud. It was not much use in preparing for the examination, as it turned out.

There is another passage in the book where Gleick cites a possibly apocryphal story which is even closer (but I do not understand the nature of this source):

> > *A physicist studying quantum field theory with Murray Gell-Mann at the California Institute of Technology in the 1950s, before standard texts have become available, discovers unpublished lecture notes by Richard Feynman, circulating samizdat style. He asks Gell-Mann about them.Gell-Mann says no, Dick’s methods are not the same as the methods used here. The student asks, well, what are Feynman’s methods? GellMann leans coyly against the blackboard and says, Dick’s method is this. **You write down the problem. You think very hard.** (He shuts his eyes and presses his knuckles parodically to his forehead.) **Then you write down the answer.***
> > However is not a good learning method.

This quote appeared also in: J. Gleick, *[Part Showman, All Genius](https://www.nytimes.com/1992/09/20/magazine/part-showman-all-genius.html)*, New York Times (1992)

The earliest version I could find of the full Feynman's technique in the form you present is from Scott Young, a self-help book author, from 2011: https://www.scotthyoung.com/learnonsteroids/grab/TranscriptFeynman.pdf before that *Feynman's technique* referred to Feynman's diagrams. A hint of that was given in another SE site: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/30138 .

Comment: Thank you, Mauricio! Yes, it seems the technique is invented by Scott. Here are more about this: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/30138

Comment: @jsx97 thanks I added that to the answer, there is quote in quote in Genius that seems closer to it by "Gell-mann" but Gleick is citing something and I do not get if it is true or not. See edit.